# NetLogo is reading empty cells from CSV file

Tags: list, netlogo

I have 3 csv files, and each of a file contains numbers in 4 rows. I created a list of list from those files (code below). The problem is that NetLogo reads empty cells from csv files and put them in the list (picture below). And I don't know why, I used this code and method for a million times, and this never happened before, there weren't any empty spaces. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance!

```
foreach [ 1 2 3 ]
    [ i ->
      set filename (word "../data/dataset_" i ".csv")  
      set dataset-list lput (csv:from-file filename) dataset-list
      show word "dataset-list " dataset-list
    ]
```

[image]

EDIT: I realized this happen because lines in csv file (excel) are not the same length. E.g. I have 5 lines with numbers:

```
1   2  3 0
18 45 56 0 89 34 45 56
 5 10 56 0 89 34 45 56 56 0 89 34 45 56 56 0 89 34 45 
0
```

However, I had this situation before, and there weren't any problems.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, it might depend on the csv file. If there was something before, even if you deleted it, it might be seen as an empty space, instead of just nothing. This happened to me with cvs:from-file after I used an Excel macro to transpose rows vs columns in a csv file.

Try this: open the csv file in Excel, delete the columns where the empty spaces are, and then (if you need the empty columns) insert new columns there. At this point it should not read them as empties, but it should skip them... (If I understand cvs:from-file correctly).